# Apache Tomcat failed to start, port already in use

Tags: tomcat

Apache tomcat 7.0.42 failed to start today on centos server.

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8009
```

I found and  killed all processes using that port using

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :8009
```

I restarted the server. 
And changed the port to 8089 or 8189, still same error

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8089
```

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: Are you even using Ajp or just Http?

Answer (score 1):

Try netstat -atn | grep 8009 and kill proc with 9 signal

Comment: `# netstat -atnp | grep 8009`
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      1777/java
`# kill -9 1777`